# How to map(NHibernate) a specified PostgreSql type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, npgsql

I have a PK (character (10)), that is mapped like that:

The load works fine with npgsql 1.0, the sql generated with loadbyid
is :

`SELECT city0_."IDCity" as IDMu1_92_0_ FROM "tblCity" city0_ WHERE
city0_."IDCity"=E'BR420240'`

Using npgsql 2.0. the sql generated is :

`SELECT city0_."IDCity" as IDMu1_92_0_ FROM "tblCity" city0_ WHERE
city0_."IDCity"='BR420240'::text`

So, I got ObjectNotFoundException, because that SQL returns 0
results...

Npgsql developer told-me to specify the exact type to the PK, in that
case : character(10)...

How can I do that using NH? I tried use **sql-type**, but I think it only
exist in Hibernate...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a NHibernate bug...